# How can I take varying amount of arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have this Discord bot with a command to add a link/password combo. Currently it can only accept two arguments, but I have users who would like to paste in a whole list of links/passwords and have them all entered at once.

This is my code now:

```
if (command === "add"){
message.delete();
let link = message.content.split(" ")[1];
let answer = message.content.split(" ")[2];
  if (!link || !answer){
  user.send('Please be sure to enter a link **and** its corresponding answer.');
  }
lockers.push({"link":link,"answer":answer});
fs.writeFile('./serverLockers.json', JSON.stringify(serverLockers), (err) => {if(err) console.error(err)});
return;
}
```

The message in this case would be string that is  "[command] [link] [answer]".

I want to be able to do something like "[command] [link] [answer],[link] [answer],[link] [answer]"

How can I change this to add multiple combos at once?
It will have to know how many combinations were entered
And the amount of combinations entered will always vary

Comment: How will the information be input? Pairs of strings representing links and answers? Objects containing the pairs? 2d Array?

Comment: It would be a string. An example would be:

"!bulkadd link.com answer, link2.com answer2, link3.com answer3"

Comment: What is `serverLockers` and how does it relate to the previous code? Where is `lockers` used, and where is it initialised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no embedded commas in the content, and you have a format like this in `message.content`:

```
"command1 link1 answer1, link2 answer2, link3 answer3"
```

then you can just first parse off the command and then split on comma and then split each of those on spaces.

```js
let message = {};
message.content =  "command1 link1 answer1, link2 answer2, link3 answer3";

let lockers = [];

// get command off the beginning
let index = message.content.indexOf(" ");
let command = message.content.slice(0, index);

// get remaining content and split it into link answer combos
let args = message.content.slice(index + 1).split(/\s*,\s*/);
// args.length is the number of combos entered
args.forEach(function(item) {
    let splits = item.split(/\s+/);
    let link = splits[0];
    let answer = splits[1];

    // code here for processing each link/answer combo (not sure what you want to do with them)
    lockers.push({"link":link,"answer":answer});
});
// final code to process lockers array
console.log("command = ", command);
console.log(lockers);
```

Comment: This seems to be perfect except there is also a command at the very beginning of the string that needs to be removed before doing this. So the string would be `"[link] [answer],[link] [answer],[link] [answer]" `



I tried doing 

`let argsOld = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
    let args = argsOld.content.split(",");`
But that does not seem to work.

Comment: @JohnDoe - OK,  you didn't include an attempt at that code to parse the command.  You seemed to already have the `command` variable loaded so I assumed you already had that code.  Anyway, I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 examples, the key is that [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) are all of the arguments passed into a function, even if they are not explicitly listed in the function definition.

```js
function doSomethingString(){
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i+=2){
    var userName = arguments[i];
    var password = arguments[i+1];
    console.log("new user, name:"+userName+" pass:"+password);
  }
}

console.log("test1\n");
doSomethingString("user1", "pass1", "user2", "pass2");

console.log("\ntest2\n");
doSomethingString("user1", "pass1");

console.log("\ntest3\n");
doSomethingString("user1", "pass1", "user2", "pass2", "user3", "pass3");
```

```js
function doSomethingObjects(){
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    var userName = arguments[i].name;
    var password = arguments[i].password;
    console.log("new user, name:"+userName+" pass:"+password);
  }
}

console.log("test1\n");
doSomethingObjects({name: "user1", password: "pass1"},{name: "user2", password: "pass2"});

console.log("\ntest2\n");
doSomethingObjects({name: "user1", password: "pass1"});

console.log("\ntest3\n");
doSomethingObjects({name: "user1", password: "pass1"},{name: "user2", password: "pass2"},{name: "user3", password: "pass3"});
```

```js
function doSomethingStringPairs(){
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    var userName = arguments[i].split(" ")[0];
    var password = arguments[i].split(" ")[1];
    console.log("new user, name:"+userName+" pass:"+password);
  }
}

console.log("test1\n");
doSomethingStringPairs("user1 pass1", "user2 pass2");

console.log("\ntest2\n");
doSomethingStringPairs("user1 pass1");

console.log("\ntest3\n");
doSomethingStringPairs("user1 pass1", "user2 pass2", "user3 pass3");
```